# Python/SqlAlchemy 3-way circular dependency

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I am having an issue with creating a set of relationships among 3 of my tables. When I run the code to create the tables I get a circular dependency error.

I tried fiddling around with `use_alter` and `post_update` based on responses to similar posts, but I wasn't able to solve the issue.

Basically a map has a set of locations, a character has a set of maps, but a character is also located on one of those map locations.
In addition, a map can have parent/child relationships with other maps.

```
class Character(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'character'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    classID = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    profileID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profile.ID'), nullable=False)
    locationID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.ID'))

    location = relationship("Location")
    maps = relationship("Map", backref="owner", cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")

class Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'map'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255))
    maptypeID = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    parentID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('map.ID'))
    ownerID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('character.ID'))

    children = relationship("Map", backref=backref("parent", remote_side="Map.ID"))
    locations = relationship("Location", backref='map', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")

class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    y = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    locationtypeID = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    mapID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('map.ID'), nullable=False)
```

How can I solve this issue?

**Edit (Solved):**

After some more playing around with `use_alter`, I was able to solve the problem by changing the mapID definition in the Location class from:

```
mapID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('map.ID'), nullable=False)
```

To:

```
mapID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('map.ID', use_alter=True, name="fk_location_map"), nullable=False)
```

In response to the recommendation of breaking the cyclic dependency, I'd rather have the correct relationships and data integrity represented in the schema. I'd much rather worry about fixing ORM issues or changing ORMs rather than fudging the schema to fit the ORM's expectations.

In this particular case, I can't think of a more concise and elegant way to represent all of the **information**(in the most fundamental sense of the word) that I need the schema to represent for the application.

Side note: Having worked with other languages/frameworks/ORMs, this kind of snafu is often automatically accounted for by the ORM. For example, in .NET E/F, I believe the FK constraints are typically added and activated after all the table creation statements.

Comment: If your problem is finding the circular dependencies in your schema, here's a Gist for that: https://gist.github.com/adewes/dea76a0cc7c56c705d74

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get alembic to help you with a cyclic dependency in your schema, but I'm not going to help you with that.   Instead, I'm going to strongly urge you to *break the cyclic dependency*.

If i'm understanding your schema, you have the rooms or buildings in your model represented by `Location`.  the players/monsters in your schema are `Character`s, which at any time must be in exactly one `location`.   Additionally, there are some `Map` items floating around, which are always *about* some specific `location`, and are always in the inventory of exactly one `character`.

So here's how I'd spell that

```
class Location:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Character:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(ForeignKey(Location.id))

    location = relationship(Location, backref="characters")

class Map:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(ForeignKey(Location.id))
    owner_id = Column(ForeignKey(Character.id))

    location = relationship(Location, backref="maps")
    owner = relationship(Character, backref="inventory")
```

Comment: That's close but not quite correct. A character only represents a player's character. A map is not an item, it's just a collection of locations with a name (and some scripts and other stuff attached to it).  The maps along with their locations are going to be dynamically generated at runtime, so I want each character to own a set of generated maps and their locations which are going to be unique to the character.

Comment: The other caveat is that a map can be a child of another map. Think along the lines of world map -> country map -> city map -> area map. So the locations in the context of a world map can represent countries while in the context of a city map they would represent areas of the city.

Comment: So er... Character -> Map* ->  Location forms a tree, with Character at the root, Location at the leaves, and an arbitrary length, acyclic path of `Map`'s between them?

Comment: It can kind of be interpreted as a tree, but I would hesitate to do so.   Every map will have locations, but every map can also have a parent map and child maps.   The locations can kind of be thought of as being orthogonal to the tree. They are there as properties of the map but have nothing to do with the hierarchy of maps. The details of how a location can connect two maps will likely be another mapping table(since there will be weird cases such as labyrinths and one location being able to lead to different maps based on certain conditions, etc).